# Is it possible to change the shortcut for Office format painter from ctrl + shift + v to something else?

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-office, shortcuts, microsoft-onenote

I am using Ditto to hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> as paste text only and it works great, however this conflicts with Onenote and paste formatting hotkey. I was wondering if it's possible to change the shortcuts that Onenote uses. Thanks

Comment: After posting this question, I found the solution at Microsoft's site https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-9a92343e-a781-4d5a-92f1-0f32e3ba5b4d 
Under "Commands Not in the Ribbon" section, found PasteFormat, and changed it to Ctrl + Shift + D and then changed the double underline (under the same section) to none (I don't use it) Not that the Keyboard Shortcuts button only shows up in Word, and not in Onenote under the same options menu section.

Comment: I cannot edit my above comment to say that unfortunately, it works in Word but not in Onenote where I need it. Since the Keyboard Shortcuts button does not show up in Onenote I'm thinking it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was hard to figure out.

I can't find out the version I have. But it seems to be **OneNote for Windows 10**. I don't know if it is the same on other versions.

As of this writing, this is the way to do it:

1. Make sure you have enabled ***Show Paste Options button when content is pasted***.

   Go to `File` > `Options` > `Advanced` > `Editing`. It is the first option.

2. Now, paste the text using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

   The Paste Options will appear next to the text. It is a small flying dropdown button.

3. On the Paste Options choose ***Keep Text Only***.

   This will convert to plain text, but still not make as default.

4. The Paste Options will still be visible. Click on it again, and then ***Set as Default Paste***

Comment: After reinstalling Ditto and configuring "paste without formatting" to the shortcut ctrl+shift+v, I am able to paste plain text within OneNote as well as other Office apps.

I cannot rule out that an update to Office or Ditto changed the behavior, or some fiddling that I did with the Keyboard Shortcuts customization in Word (see my comment to the question).

I also toggled the office clipboard settings but this did not affect the behavior in testing (I was trying to disable the office clipboard entirely which is not possible)